# How can I reduce Kafka log file size of Alpakka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am doing data replication in alpakka using Consumer.commitableSource. But, the size of kafka log file is increases very quickly. The size reaches 5 gb in a day. As a solution of this problem, ı want to delete processed data immediately. I am using delete record method in AdminClient to delete offset. But when I look at the log file, data corresponding to that offset is not deleted.

Comment: The Kafka LogCleaner thread is synchronous and periodic. You typically shouldn't be pin-pointing an offset to delete, rather setting retention sizes of bytes or hours/days/milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

When using `commitableSource` you need to acknowledge that the record has been successfully read and is ready to be cleaned by committing the offset. You can do that by calling `commitJavadsl()`. Take a look at the [example in the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html#offset-storage-in-kafka-committing) for more information.